# How to write a nacl program that integrates with a jsoncpp naclport

Tags: google-nativeclient

Naclports seems to just provide a 32-bit object files, how do I get my project to link against them? Is there any tutorials on how someone uses jsoncpp in a nacl program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a sample for you that you can checkout here:

https://github.com/johnmccutchan/NaClJsonCpp

The build system is premake based, you can download premake4 here:

http://industriousone.com/premake

From a terminal (cygwin or *nix):

```
premake4 gmake
make -R
```

Will build and link the project.

To test it run:

```
python ./http.py
```

then navigate to localhost:5103. You should see the following:

```
NaCl Json Cpp Test

Status: SUCCESS


Loading plug-in ruby
Loading plug-in c++
Loading plug-in python
Sample Running.
Instance Built: 14:41:31 (Sep 5 2012)
```

To see how Json Cpp was used see the function JsonCPP in nacl_sample_main.cpp.

Let me know if you have any questions.